# Hadoop jobs getting poor locality

Tags: optimization, hadoop, configuration

I have some fairly simple Hadoop streaming jobs that look like this:

```
yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101.jar \
  -files hdfs:///apps/local/count.pl \
  -input /foo/data/bz2 \
  -output /user/me/myoutput \
  -mapper "cut -f4,8 -d," \
  -reducer count.pl \
  -combiner count.pl
```

The `count.pl` script is just a simple script that accumulates counts in a hash and prints them out at the end - the details are probably not relevant but I can post it if necessary.

The input is a directory containing 5 files encoded with bz2 compression, roughly the same size as each other, for a total of about 5GB (compressed).

When I look at the running job, it has 45 mappers, but they're all running on one node.  The particular node changes from run to run, but always only one node.  Therefore I'm achieving poor data locality as data is transferred over the network to this node, and probably achieving poor CPU usage too.

The entire cluster has 9 nodes, all the same basic configuration.  The blocks of the data for all 5 files are spread out among the 9 nodes, as reported by the HDFS Name Node web UI.

I'm happy to share any requested info from my configuration, but this is a corporate cluster and I don't want to upload any full config files.

It looks like this previous thread [ [why map task always running on a single node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135949/why-map-task-always-running-on-a-single-node) ] is relevant but not conclusive.

**EDIT:** at @jtravaglini's suggestion I tried the following variation and saw the same problem - all 45 map jobs running on a single node:

```
yarn jar \
  /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101.jar \
  wordcount /foo/data/bz2 /user/me/myoutput
```

At the end of the output of that task in my shell, I see:

```
            Launched map tasks=45
            Launched reduce tasks=1
            Data-local map tasks=18
            Rack-local map tasks=27
```

which is the number of data-local tasks you'd expect to see on one node just by chance alone.

Comment: Are you sure every node has bz2 compression capability ? if not then the uncompression will only happen on the node that has that capability and situations like this may arise.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to reproduce this behavior without streaming in the mix?  Say, with hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples WordCount?

Comment: @Jijo - I don't think your first comment (setting class/jar) matters, since the job does actually succeed.  As for the second comment (bz2), I see similar behavior if I decompress first and run on the plain text files.  It fires off 120 jobs, 100 of which are on one node and 20 on another node.

Comment: @jtravaglini - yes, I get the same results with the `wordcount` example.  I'll add that to the original question.

Comment: Does it also happen if you submit using 'hadoop jar' vs. 'yarn jar'?  Trying to isolate the variables here...

Comment: @jtravaglini - yes, same result with `hadoop jar`.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial questions... how are you determining that all mappers are running on one node?  Is it possible to share Job logs, a screenshot with all task attempts running in the same NodeManager, etc.?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you may have some `ssh-keygen` issues among your nodes in the cluster. (PROBABLY). Try doing an `ssh _your_hosts_` among one and all roughly and let us know your thoughts

Comment: I don't think it's a keygen issue, because the particular nodes where the jobs run changes from one invocation to the next.

Comment: I know they’re all running on one node because in the Ambari interface (we’re using the free Hortonworks distro) I can see that all the Map jobs are assigned to the same IP address.  I can confirm it by SSH-ing to that node and I see all the jobs running there, using 'top' or 'ps' or whatever, whereas if I SSH to any other node, I see no jobs running.  Finally, when I submit a job from the shell (e.g. the wordcount job) I see its stats are bad:

Comment: (added stats to the question text)